# pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [asteriskpbx]

Tags: sudo, init.d, sudoedit

to install the asterisk program, I created a sudo user and added to  /etc/sudoers file like this:

```
asteriskpbx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but, when I try to start the service, I get the following report:

```
Jun 15 15:18:03 localhost.localdomain sudo[1023]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jun 15 15:18:03 localhost.localdomain sudo[1023]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [asteriskpbx]
```

why can't it login? I have already added to the sudoers file to use no password.

Answer (score 1):

What did you use to create the user?

My preliminary test shows that a simple

```
useradd <login>
visudo 
# in visudo
<login> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
# save and exit visudo

# as another user 
$ sudo -u <login> hostname -f
$ sudo -u <login> -s
```

Should work without any further problems, what does the asterisk log tells you ?

Did you by any chance set a password on that new user ?

Remember `<login>` is a placeholder, please change it to what you feel needed, and I would recommend you to use `useradd -r <login>` as `-r` is system account.

What shell is your account using, the account that is not able to start up asterisk? Look in /etc/passwd

Do you use LDAP on your network and did you configure your machine to lookup using LDAP?

Comment: I mistakenly set a password for the user. I removed the password from /etc/passwd. thank you for your hints.